# Problem with font rendering on certain applications

Tags: libreoffice, fonts, pyqt

Installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS  with Xfce 4.12 on my Thinkpad T440P a few weeks back. This was my first real contact with Linux systems.

My problem is that the font used in the GUI of some of the applications (LibreOffice 5.2.6.2, one school project which is written in Python and uses PyQt5 for the GUI) is literally unreadable. It seems to me that these applications are using some sort of Greek style font for the GUI.

[image: LibreOffice screenshot]

Does anyone have any ideas what is wrong with my system?

Edit: Ran the `locale` command, output below.

```
~$ locale  
LANG=en_US.UTF-8  
LANGUAGE=en_US  
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_NUMERIC=fi_FI.UTF-8  
LC_TIME=fi_FI.UTF-8  
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_MONETARY=fi_FI.UTF-8  
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_PAPER=fi_FI.UTF-8  
LC_NAME=fi_FI.UTF-8  
LC_ADDRESS=fi_FI.UTF-8  
LC_TELEPHONE=fi_FI.UTF-8  
LC_MEASUREMENT=fi_FI.UTF-8  
LC_IDENTIFICATION=fi_FI.UTF-8  
LC_ALL=
```

Edit2. Ran the `fc-match -s | head` command, output below.

```
~$ fc-match -s | head  
DejaVuSans.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Book"  
DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Bold"  
n019003l.pfb: "Nimbus Sans L" "Regular"  
Waree.ttf: "Waree" "Regular"  
Laksaman.ttf: "Laksaman" "Regular"  
NotoSansCJK-Regular.ttc: "Noto Sans CJK JP" "Regular"  
KhmerOS.ttf: "Khmer OS" "Regular"  
NanumGothic.ttf: "NanumGothic" "Regular"  
Lohit-Punjabi.ttf: "Lohit Punjabi" "Regular"  
lklug.ttf: "LKLUG" "Regular"
```

Comment: Can you please run the `locale` command in terminal and show us what it outputs (by editing your question).

Comment: Looks like it's English written in the Greek alphabet. E.g. the menu at the top says "Φιλε, Τοολσ, Ηελρ", which is "File, Tools, Help".

Comment: This is really odd. What's the output of the command: `fc-match -s | head`

Comment: Ran the `fc-match -s | head` command.

Comment: The `fc-match` output looks normal to me. I'm out of ideas. Hopefully someone else can spot the cause.